# PBi Date for line chart Forecast and Actual year

Tags: powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, datamodel

this is my data model:[image: Data model]

I want to create a line chart with Forecast and Actual data in one line. I have disabled interactions for "Last X Days" filter. Datekey looks like "20230101" (it is number from date).

Created measure for>

1. the actual year:
   Test AY = CALCULATE(SUM(Consumption[suma_odpoctov_kwh]), ALL(Months_with_Total[Month Name]))
2. the forecast year:
   Test FC = CALCULATE(SUM(Forecast[Spotreba_kWh]), ALL(Months_with_Total[Month Name]))

This calculates for all months all tariffs and only 3 months (January, February, March). I have tried removefilters, all(), crossfilter but nothing works. Can you help me, please?
[image]